How to compile Kotlin into WebAssembly in command line?
I would like to compile a few Kotlin classes and enums into WebAssembly in command line. It worked several years ago with kotlinc-native but the wasm32 target was removed. I try to use this example:
kotlinc-js -output lib.js -Xir-produce-js -Xwasm -libraries kotlin-stdlib-wasm-2.0.20.klib input.kt but the lib directory has no file named kotlin-stdlib-wasm-2.0.20.klib in Kotlin 2.0.20. How can I simply compile Kotlin into WebAssembly without using Intellij IDEA (and Gradle)?

Confused as to what you mean with "lib directory has no file named kotlin-stdlib-wasm-2.0.20.klib", you are supposed to link the path to the library, which you either build yourself or just download prebuilt from jetbrains. I don't know if that will "work" as afaik building wasm libraries from CLI without gradle is not supported. Ie. you'd probably need to reverse engineer the gradle plugin to do it.

Follow these steps:

Run git clone https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-wasm-browser-template.git
Edit KotLin version number in gradle/libs.versions.toml if you want to use another version
Add -Xwasm-generate-wat into build.gradle.kts as stated here
Replace the Kotlin source and test files by your own files
Run gradle build
Go to build/dist, you should find a subdirectory named compileSync containing the resulting WAT file

N.B: I don't need IntelliJ IDEA but I haven't found a solution working without Gradle.
